# Pi 4B not booting when powered via power pins on extension header

Tags: pi-4, power-supply

I used to power my Pi 3B and 3B+ from and external shield board of my design, which features 5A power source, connecting +5V to pins 2 and 4, and GND to 6, 14, 30, 34 and 39. It worked just fine, however recently I wanted to upgrade to Pi 4B 4GB - and it no longer works, Pi simply won't start. When I connect it to my PC via USB-C cable, it starts just fine, but keeps showing under-voltage warning - no surprise there, since USB 3 only provides 0,9A as opposed to recommended 2,5A.

My power source is fine - like I said, it's 5 amps, so it's way more than required by PI and way more than USB port provides. I measured the output of my power source while Pi is powered on, and it's a perfect 5V.

There are two diodes next to USB-C port. When I power the PI from my PC, the green one shines continuously, however when powering it via my board, the red one shines  and green one blinks a few times. I read the post speciffic to Pi 4 on the official forum:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=437084#p437084

but the green LED blink in a completely random manner.

Does Pi 4 no longer allow powering the board via GPIO pins? If that's not the case, then what might be the issue?

Comment: PoE hats supply power through the 5v pins, so, yes, Pi 4 does allow power from the 5v pins on the extension header (technically, they are not GPIO pins, they are power pins - some people are pedantic about that, I'm not one of those)

Comment: Like I said, Pi is not dead because it works just fine when powered from PC.

Comment: Fair enough - I misunderstood - anyway, there's no problem powering the pi 4 through pins on the extension header - I have 3 pi4's with PoE's doing just that - but still, count the blinks - it's usually a sign it can't boot

Comment: Yes, it can't boot, that's the core of the issue. The question is - why.

Comment: well, the blink pattern usually tells you, unfortunately *blinks a few times* is not one of the patterns that is documented - I wasn't getting you to count the blinks to be a dick

Comment: Unfortunatelly it's impossible to make out any pattern to green LED's blinks, it's completely random.

Comment: so, it's booting

Comment: So it seems, apparently green LED indicates that SD card is being read, except nothing shows on the screen.

Comment: really odd behaviour

Answer (score 2):

As a first guess, based on your description of "random" blinking of the ACT (green activity LED), I'd say that your RPi ***is*** booting, but your monitor is not cooperating when powered from the headers. This should be verified before proceeding with trouble-shooting.

And so, Step 1 is to test login to your RPi via SSH. If you've never logged into your RPi via SSH, you should familiarize yourself with how this is done:

> If you do not recall adding an empty file named `ssh` to the `/boot` directory of your microSD card, do that first. For example: mount `/boot`, then `touch /boot/ssh`.

If you're able to connect/login to your RPi 4 using SSH, you'll know your problem is related to the HDMI hardware/firmware/software. We can proceed from that point, or you may wish to do a further search - [perhaps similar to this one](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=raspberry+pi+4+starts+but+no+video+display&t=ffab&atb=v278-1&ia=web).

Answer (score 0):

I have a few Pi4B, none powered via USB.

I generate the 5.1V from 12V used to power magnetic discs with a low cost Chinese voltage regulator which has a multi turn potentiometer.

My Pi's work best with 5.2V and can run the whole day without any glitches.